# C-style array in C++ map

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

Note: this question is only about maps and arrays in C++. It only so happens that I'm using OpenGL, so those without OpenGL knowledge should not be discouraged from reading further.

I'm trying to put a C-style array inside a C++ `std::map` for later use when setting a color.

```
const map<int, GLfloat[3]> colors = { // 
    {1, {0.20. 0.60. 0.40}},          //
    ...                               // This produces an error.
    {16, {0.5, 0.25, 0.75}}           //
};                                    //

...

int key = 3;
glColor3fv(colors.at(key));
```

This does not compile because:

```
Semantic Issue
Array initializer must be an initializer list
```

...but I did specify an initializer list, didn't I? Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type `GLfloat[3]`, as a value type, does not meet the following requirements of associative containers.

1. It is not `EmplaceConstructible`.
2. It is not `CopyInsertable`.
3. It is not `CopyAssignable`.

More details can be found at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/AssociativeContainer.

You can create a helper class to help you along.

```
struct Color
{
   GLfloat c[3];
   GLfloat& operator[](int i) {return c[i];}
   GLfloat const& operator[](int i) const {return c[i];}
};

const std::map<int, Color> colors = {
    {1, {0.20, 0.60, 0.40}},
    {16, {0.5, 0.25, 0.75}}
};
```

Comment: @MarcusMcLean, you can add `GLfloat* data() { return c; }` to `Color` to make it usable with other functions that need `GLfloat*`.

Comment: the `struct Color` is essentially `std::array<GLfloat,3>`

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia, agreed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that arrays have neither copy constructor nor copy assignment operator. Instead of a C array use standard C++ container `std::array` that has the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    const std::map<int, std::array<float,3>> colors = 
    {
        { 1, { 0.20, 0.60, 0.40 } },
        { 16, { 0.5, 0.25, 0.75 } }
    };  

    return 0;
}
```

For simplicity I used type `float` instead of `GLfloat` in the example .

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
using std;
using namespace boost::assign;

map<int, GLfloat[3]> colors  = map_list_of (1, {0.20. 0.60. 0.40}) (16, {0.5, 0.25, 0.75});
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score -3):

It is not gonna be faster maybe, do to cache misses.

Use a sorted std::vector or `array<std::pair<const Key, Value>` and use std::lower/upper_bound to look for the element you want to look for. That will be faster, I guess.

Comment: So what is the rationale to make a *negative* vote out of this?