# Creating a std::map containing 2d arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures, stdmap

I was trying to create a map to associate  2d arrays to characters. I tried to do it in this way:

```
map<char, bool[6][4]> m;
bool charA[6][4] = { 0,1,1,0,
                     1,0,0,1,
                     1,1,1,1,
                     1,0,0,1,
                     1,0,0,1,
                     1,0,0,1 };

m.insert(make_pair('a', charA));
```

But it doesn't work; maybe because the array is not dynamically allocated?

Comment: Don't use raw c-style arrays. In c++ you should use `std::map<char,std::array<std::array<bool,4>,6>>>`

Comment: It doesn't work because arrays can't be assigned to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and have access to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) compiler or newer versions, use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of the c-style array.

In your case, you can replace it with
`std::array<std::array<bool, 4>, 6>`.
Now you can do as follows: [See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aae159xdr)

```
#include <array> // std::array

std::map<char, std::array<std::array<bool, 4>, 6>> m;
std::array<std::array<bool, 4>, 6> arr = { 0,1,1,0,
                       1,0,0,1,
                       1,1,1,1,
                       1,0,0,1,
                       1,0,0,1,
                       1,0,0,1 };

// now you can
m.emplace('a', arr); // construct the entry in-place (std::map::emplace)
```

---

> Maybe because the array is not dynamically allocated?

This has nothing to do with the allocations, rather the problem is with the c-style arrays. You simply **can not copy** it to the map like that. In other words, not copyable!

More read:

- [C-style array in C++ map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199551/c-style-array-in-c-map)
- [How can I use an array as map value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582529/how-can-i-use-an-array-as-map-value)

---

**Future reads**:

As *@TedLyngmo* pointed out, in the given example, even the  [`std::map::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) is used, a copy of the array (i.e. `arr`) will take place. This could be much expensive for larger arrays or arrays with data types, which are expensive to copy. In that case, you need to use the `std::map::emplace`, in the way shown in the linked website.

You can refer to the following examples for further examples:

- [How to use emplace in map for custom class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645539/how-to-use-emplace-in-map-for-custom-class)
- [Emplace directly in std::map of pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906637/emplace-directly-in-stdmap-of-pair)
- [Optimal creation new empty element in std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343970/optimal-creation-new-empty-element-in-stdmap)